# How to host webservice on bluemix?

Tags: web-services, ibm-cloud, continuous-delivery

I have an HTTP service written in Node.js

> var server = http.createServer(function(request,response) {...});
>      server.listen(listenerPort);

When I deploy to Bluemix how/where do I assign a public endpoint and port#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are ready to deploy to Bluemix you can use the [PORT environment variable](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/index.html#nodejs_runtime) accessible by using `process.env.PORT`. There is also a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv) to help you with parsing Cloud Foundry environment variables like PORT

To decide the host name for your application- The app name will be the default host name. for example `cf push myapp` will assign you the url `myapp.mybluemix.net`

You can also assign a host name using the [host key in your manifest.yml](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#host) OR using `cf push myapp -n myhostname`

Answer (score 0):

Blumix provides an environment variable with the port.

> // cfenv provides access to your Cloud Foundry environment
>
> // for more info, see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cfenv
>
> var cfenv = require('cfenv');
>
> // get the app environment from Cloud Foundry
>
> var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
>
> server.listen(appEnv.port);